# QGIS OpenLayers Plugin - Question about Google Maps/Earth Policy

Tags: qgis, google-maps, google-earth, openlayers-2, license

I am operating on OS X version 10.9.5 using QGIS 2.6.1 - Brighton. I am using the OpenLayers Plugin version 1.3.6 (Google maps) to create shapefiles and edit existing shapefiles over the Google map plugin data. I happened notice that in the Google Maps/Earth Permissions page under "Geo Permissions" a FAQ was posed:

http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

"I'd like to trace a map using your imagery. Can I?" The response: "You may not use Google Maps or Google Earth as the basis for tracing your own maps or other geographic content."

My question: Does QGIS have some sort of agreement with Google Maps/Earth which allow the mapping community to use the plugin they have provided? Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such agreement. You have to obey the Google terms of license regardless of the software you use.

See also [Is the use of Google Earth imagery via the OpenLayers Plugin in QGIS legal?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102324/is-the-use-of-google-earth-imagery-via-the-openlayers-plugin-in-qgis-legal)